# LINQ throwing Query nested too deeply exception

Tags: linq, exception, subquery

I have the following class and objects

```
Product{int ProdId{get; set;}, string ProdDesc{get; set;}}

IQueryable<Product> products = ProductRepository.GetAllProducts();

List<int> filteredProdIds = new List<int>();
```

The `GetAllProducts()` method performs a couple of joins over some **EF classes** and gives back a `IQueryable<Product>` object. I already tested whether it gives back the expected values and it does.

From `products` I want to get all the records that have their `ProdId` in `filteredProdIds` (assume that `filteredProdIds` has already been filled with `Ids`):

```
products = products.Where(p => filteredProdIds.Any(fp => fp.Equals(p.ProdId)));
```

Whn I launch my application, it throws an exception

*Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.*

I tried to verify the query with **LINQPad**, by replacing the `GetAllProducts()` method with an equivalent **database view**, and it works.

What can be the cause of this exception?

**UPDATE**

filteredProductIds is filled by this method:

```
IEnumerable<int> filteredProductIds = products.Select(p => p.partId).Distinct().ToList();
```

I found a way to avoid this exception but there must be a much cleaner solution:

```
foreach (var filteredProdId in filteredProdIds)
{
   product.Union(product.Where(p => p.ProdId.Equals(filteredProdId)));
}
product.Distinct();
```

Comment: Maybe this can clarify the problem: http://blog.hompus.nl/2010/08/26/joining-an-iqueryable-with-an-ienumerable/

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit to how many items can be within `filteredProdIds`, since it is a List.

To test you can set `filteredProdIds` to:

```
filteredProdIds = filteredProdIds.Take(1).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean? Usually you specify a bound on the items when you use an array, with the List the allocation is dynamic, therefore theoretically there is no upper bound

Comment: @CiccioMiami - If you are using *linq-to-objects* you will be fine, but since you are using linq-to-entites there is a limit to the size of the list. To test try setting: *filteredProdIds = filteredProdIds.Take(1).ToList();*

Comment: sorry but I don't understand your point. I put a watch when filteredProdIds is filled with data and it is properly filled.

Comment: @CiccioMiami - Can you show the code where you populate *filteredProdIds*? *filteredProdIds.Count* would also be helpful

Comment: The Count is equal to 104. The code is a function that returns a IEnumerable<int>, therefore the filteredProdIds is populated without deferring the query execution. I will update the code

Answer (score 1):

```
var filteredProdIds = FilterIds().ToArray();
var products = ProductRepository.GetAllProducts().Where(p => filteredProdIds.Contains(p.ProdId));
```

Comment: Why do you use Contains directly on filteredProdIds? You are comparing int[] with int, it will give a runtime error. Moreover with Contains if ProdId = 2, the expression will return true for all the values of filteredProdIds that contain a 2, such as 12, 20, 21, 22, etc...

Comment: Did you try @CiccioMiami ? It should translate into something like `WHERE ProductId IN (1,2,3,...`. The `IN` contains integers, so 2 will not match 12.